# Combining data frame multiple rows into single row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this data frame.

```
   userId  movieId                tag
0       2    60756              funny
1       2    60756    Highly quotable
2       2    60756       will ferrell
3       2    89774       Boxing story
4       2    89774                MMA
5       2    89774          Tom Hardy
6       2   106782              drugs
7       2   106782  Leonardo DiCaprio
8       2   106782    Martin Scorsese
9       7    48516       way too long
```

I want to combine tag column with corresponding movieId and userId such as.

```
   userId  movieId                tag
0       2    60756              funny|Highly quotable|will ferrell
1       2    89774       Boxing story|MMA|Tom Hardy
2       2   106782              drugs|Leonardo DiCaprio|Martin Scorsese
3       2    5643                fun
4       7    48516       way too long
```

I have tried this code but it is not considering userId for every movie.

```
result_df = df.groupby('movieId').agg({'tag': list}).apply(lambda r: '|'.join(r['tag']), axis=1).reset_index()
result_df.columns = ['movieId', 'tag']
```

Comment: Use: `df = df.groupby(['userId','movieId'])['tag'].agg('|'.join).reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael How can i append above resultant data frame with another dataframe which has two common columns ```userId, movieId``` such that for specific user and movie,  tag value should be appended. If there is no tag value then fill with Nan.

Comment: Can you check data output?